# Ajax POST giving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am new to ajax and I was just trying out some examples of ajax but I keep getting this 500 Internal Server Error. I've searching through the web for a solution but nothing seems to work. However, if i change the type from POST to GET, it works fine.

controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class testingAjax extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('testingAjax_view');
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        $values = $this->input->post('testing');        
    echo $values;
    }
}
```

js script

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
        $('#callBackBtn').click(function()
        {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testingAjax/getSomething",
                data: {testing: "testing"},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#responseText').val(data);
                },
                error: function(xhr, text_status, error_thrown){
                    alert(error_thrown);
                }

            })              
        });
    }
);
```

view

```
<body>
    <h3>Testing Ajax</h3>
    <div class="entry-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="input_text">
        <input type="button" value="Ajax Call Back" id="callBackBtn"/>
    </div>
    <div class="response_wrapper">
        <textarea id="responseText"></textarea>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm running this on xammp. Below are the apache error logs (not sure if they are useful or not)

```
[Wed May 13 00:31:53.251642 2015] [core:notice] [pid 25716:tid 456] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed May 13 00:31:53.257646 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 25716:tid 456] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 25724
[Wed May 13 00:31:57.895294 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 25724:tid 460] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed May 13 00:31:59.065692 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 25724:tid 460] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed May 13 00:31:59.205786 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 25724:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Firebug shown error:

```
POST http://localhost/ias/testingAjax/getSomething      
500 Internal Server Error
        30ms
```

Comment: You have no form and your AJAX isn't sending anything to the server.

Comment: form is not a problem but the problem is  at least you have to send something to server,that's not happening in your code.

Comment: I've made some edits and now i have some data that are sent to the server but it's still not working either.

Comment: i added the error shown from my firebug

Comment: @John please mark and up-vote the answer for others help.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I created a fresh copy of your work and here a simple one that you could follow.

First is to setup properly your project.

First I create a .htaccess file to the root folder of the folder same directory to the index.php to create a pretty URL

Here is a simple .htaccess content file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>
```

And you need to enable the mod_rewrite extension/configuration of your server

you can enable it by finding appache/httpd.conf

and find the "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"

remove the # and save and restart you appache.

Next step is to enable URL helper

on

application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

to make use of url helper created by CI;

See [URL HELPER](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Next is to setup default controller to do this 
application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'testingAjax';
```

The controller testingAjax.php

```
<?php

class testingAjax extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('testingAjax_view');
    }

    public function getSomething()
    {
        $values = $this->input->post('testing');        
        echo $values;
    }
}
```

The view testingAjax_view.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // get the base url of the project
            var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <h3>Testing Ajax</h3>

    <div class="entry-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="input_text">
        <input type="button" value="Ajax Call Back" id="callBackBtn"/>
    </div>

    <div class="response_wrapper">
        <textarea id="responseText"></textarea>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready( function() {

            $('#callBackBtn').on('click', function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: BASE_URL + "testingAjax/getSomething",
                    data: {testing: $('#input_text').val()},
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#responseText').val(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, text_status, error_thrown){
                        alert(error_thrown);
                    }

                });

                // But if you cannot setup the pretty url
                // using .htaccess
                // then you can use the
                // BASE_URL+ "index.php/" + "testingAjax/getSomething
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
url:"/testingAjax/getSomething".
```

For ajax call  default method is `GET` and you didn't post any `form` or any value to server, just making ajax call on button click that's why it may works!!! when you changed method type from `POST` to `GET` but first of all i think you should fix the `url`

> Method (default: 'GET')
>
> Type: String The HTTP method to use for the
>
> request (e.g. "POST", "GET", "PUT")

see more here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I think the person down-voted because it's a controller class function you want to call through this url which is not possible at all in this manner

Comment: Im using firebug to debug and it seems that the url is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your .htaccess file which is in your root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Note:**

`RewriteBase /` is important here.